# Eclipse crashing on startup

Tags: eclipse

i am using 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10 and I have Eclipse (exactly adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030) with SDK, I am trying to learn how to make my own Android application but Eclipse is closing automatically and randomly with no errors or warning. I run it in terminal and then it shows me some issues.

This is the terminal output:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fbcae8f2c91, pid=5707, tid=140449979574016

 JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6ac91]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/anarki/Dokumenty/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/eclipse/hs_err_pid5707.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
 instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Answer (score 3):

I add following line  to eclipse.ini

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

and

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to config.ini , and my probelm solved.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this answer on stackoverflow will solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20204258

Technically it is just a workaround, but it solved my problem.

**the link content:**

> Check bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776 . I suggest you > to upgrade to the newest Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler).
>
> Alternativelly you can try workaround suggested in comment #6:
>
> For a workaround add the following to the end of your eclipse.ini
>
> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
>
> ~ answered Nov 25 '13 at 22:00 [Pavel Horal]

Comment: Getting the same error on ubuntu 15.04 but this didn't fix the issue :(