# Eclipse (ADT) crash Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled

Tags: 64-bit, java, eclipse

i found my problem here:
[how to fix “Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled” error while running java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332489/how-to-fix-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled-error-whil)
and 
here:
[Eclipse crashing on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396525/eclipse-crashing-on-startup)
and here:
[Eclipse continue crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash/20204258#20204258)

Nothing help me;

This is the problem:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa434ffc2a1, pid=6989, tid=140346763503360
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I did this:
To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
and also not help;

I tried to upgrade, but i had dependency problems.

In the last few days i tried to install Cisco packet Tracer, this mean i install and uninstall some stuff (like ia386 - something - i dont remember the package name).

If i cant fix this, I thinking to do a fresh installation of ADT or over to Intellij.

To do a fresh installation (how i should backup all my plugins?)

Comment: I have the same Error too

Comment: FYI: This is the "follow-up article" for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522606/no-auto-completion-on-eclipse-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had install the last java version "1.8.0_05" and a fresh ADT and the crash disappear, 
I don't know what produce this, but a good shortcut to this problem is re-install, and finish this.

Comment: Java 1.8.0_05 surely didn't help.

Comment: Hey, after this error, I had another one that not remember now, I move to Intellij IDEA, Best IDE ever.. Try it...

Comment: This is wrong, Java v7 vs. v8 has nothing to do with this specific crash - how does one "appeal" this as the correct accepted answer to this question - the -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla from the other answer above is correct.

Comment: Could be, I don't know, I don't tried it , because I did it before he answer my question, and what I did help me.

Answer (score 51):

To solve this issue, try to put this line (slightly different from *-Dorg...*)

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

at the end of this file

```
eclipse/configuration/config.ini
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but i already fixed it. can you tell me please what this line (org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla) Should do?

Comment: This worked for me, too. Why does this fix it?

Comment: re. Qs "why does this fix it" and "what this line does", see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334466, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420030.

Comment: that is insane. but it works, thanks for the help.

Comment: This work for me too i use ADT bundled with eclipse (ubnutu 14.04 java version 1.8_u5) by going to this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash you will get extra informations on this eclips bug.

Comment: It worked for me too? How does it work? Why this error?

Comment: why is it showing access denied when I am trying to add that line in config.ini file?

Comment: Hello, i am facing this problem in ubuntu 17.10 while using AndroidStudio, So can you please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue, put this line:

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

at the end of this file

```
eclipse/configuration/config.ini
```

and it'll work fine !!