# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, crash, jre, jvm

I wanted to install `WindRiver Workbench` for VxWorks development on my Linux host. I got the correct license file and everything but my JRE seems to crash, I get the error:

```
Launching installer...  
#  
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:  
#  
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x7adcf86d, pid=19272, tid=3066465088  
#  
# JRE version: 6.0_21-b06  
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode linux-x86 )  
# Problematic frame:  
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x5486d]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d  
#  
# An error report file with more information is saved as:  
# /home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2/hs_err_pid19272.log  
#  
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:  
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp  
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.  
#
```

Any idea how I can fix this, the log in `/home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2/hs_err_pid19272.log1` is huge but the very bottom portion looks like:

```
VM Arguments:  
jvm_args: -Xmx256m -Declipse.exitdata=   -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf.retry=5   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire.header=error   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=error   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=error   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog   -Declipse.p2.max.threads=1   
java_command: /home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -showsplash -launcher /home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2/wrInstaller -name WrInstaller --launcher.library /home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so -startup /home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 778001b -data @none -sdf /media/reg/DVD-R147826.1-1-01/sdf.xml -installPath /home/reg/WindRiver -vm /home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2//jre/1.6.0_21/bin/java -vmargs -Xmx256m -Declipse.exitdata= -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf.retry=5 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire.header=error -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=error -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=error -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Declipse.p2.max.threads=1 -jar /home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2/jre/1.6.0_21/lib/i386/client:/home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2/jre/1.6.0_21/lib/i386:/home/reg/WindRiver/maintenance/wrInstaller/x86-linux2/jre/1.6.0_21/../lib/i386
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x4302b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x4302b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x355940], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00001000, sa_flags=0x10000000
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x355940], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x355940], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x358580], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x3582b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x3582b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x3582b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x3582b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:jessie/sid

uname:Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686
libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 15917, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:0.91 0.58 1.02

CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 2063836k(165332k free), swap 1046524k(639400k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b16) for linux-x86 JRE (1.6.0_21-b06), built on Jun 22 2010 01:22:50 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.1-7a (J2SE release)

time: Wed May 14 14:09:54 2014
elapsed time: 148 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried adding the the below line to the end of eclipse.ini, but Eclipse can't start at all:

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

I think there is some typo error, the line should be:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , the problem was solved adding the following to the end of eclipse.ini

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

SOURCES:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash

[Eclipse (ADT) crash Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457506/eclipse-adt-crash-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled)