# Removal of Eclipse completely

Tags: eclipse

Whenever i am trying to run an applet in my Eclipse,it's showing this error.This error was not showing when I tried to run the same program some days before.

```
Smooth is not supported by this hardware (or driver)
Unfolding Map v0.9.7 (UCSD edition)
Using OpenGLMapDisplay with processing.opengl.PGraphics2D
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4168bcc040, pid=3497,tid=139919047476992
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_72-b15) (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.72-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [i965_dri.so+0x3ca040]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/coder/workspace/UCSDUnfoldingMaps/build/hs_err_pid3497.log
Compiled method (nm)   22323 2003     n 0       jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.GLX::dispatch_glXSwapBuffers0 (native)
total in heap  [0x00007f417c977f50,0x00007f417c9782a0] = 848
relocation     [0x00007f417c978078,0x00007f417c9780c0] = 72
main code      [0x00007f417c9780c0,0x00007f417c978298] = 472
oops           [0x00007f417c978298,0x00007f417c9782a0] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I tried the solutions given in [Eclipse (ADT) crash Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457506/eclipse-adt-crash-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled) discussions but it is of no use.

Another problem I am facing is that I even can't uninstall eclipse.Whenever I am trying to do so using the commands

> sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse

or by using the command

> sudo apt-get purge eclipse

It says that the package eclipse is not installed so not removed.But I did install Eclipse.
So it will be better if anyone could give me the exact way to uninstall eclipse completely for fresh installation.I downloaded the tar.gz file initially and then extracted it for the initial setup of eclipse.

Comment: `apt-get` will only remove things installed with `apt-get`. You installed the program with a .tar.gz package, basically by source; in the same file you should find the instructions to uninstall.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find such thing.Is there any way to uninstall it  by command line?

Comment: After downloading the `.tar.gz` file, how did you exactly install it? Only locally?

Comment: @Jacob After downloading the tar file i extracted it and then by giving the gksu nautilus command I copy pasted the eclipse file in opt and then made a desktop entry for getting it on dash.That's it

Comment: Could paste (somewhere) the output of `ls -l /opt`?

Comment: total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan  8 15:35 google

Comment: If that is all (?), there is no `eclipse` directory nor -file in `/opt`. The question then is where your `eclipse` executable is located. If you run it from a launcher, please look if the file `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` exists by running the command `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`. If so, please look at the (first) line, starting with `Exec=` in the file that opens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35868/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-rahul-singh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rather than uninstalling Eclipse you should fix it. It's one of the necessary IDE which is needed by any Java Programmers. You can try a newer version of Eclipse like MARs if needed that comes with the installer also.
Coming back to original question it seems you have unzipped/untar the Eclipse. So your best bet is to search where it is installed and then simply do

```
rm -rf <one level above the Eclipse installation dir>
```

to remove it completely.

Comment: I have installed it in opt .so should i first go to opt/eclipse?

Comment: rm -rf /opt/eclipse should be the right way of removing it

Comment: If this solves your problem(removing eclipse)-do accept it as a solution and tick mark it.

Comment: Ok.but it doesn't work out.It says  cannot remove and then permission denied

Comment: sudo rm -rf /opt/eclipse

Comment: No help bro.It just asks for the password and then just prompts back to the next line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35869/discussion-between-ashu-and-rahul-singh).